# How to slide a DIV on link click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following HTML:

```
<div id="trt" style="position: relative; height: 40px;">
    <a href="#" style="text-align: center" class="a_demo_three third_button">
        M E N U
    </a>
</div>
<div id="tst" style="position: relative; height: 200px; width: 200px; background-color: #FF0000; display: none;">
    THIS IS THE INNER MENU
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.a_demo_three {
    background-color:#3bb3e0;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size:12px;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#fff;
    position:relative;
    padding:10px 20px;
    border-left:solid 1px #2ab7ec;
    margin-left:35px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(44,160,202) 0%, rgb(62,184,229) 100%);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(44,160,202) 0%, rgb(62,184,229) 100%);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(44,160,202) 0%, rgb(62,184,229) 100%);
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(44,160,202) 0%, rgb(62,184,229) 100%);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(44,160,202) 0%, rgb(62,184,229) 100%);
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(
    linear,
    left bottom,
    left top,
    color-stop(0, rgb(44,160,202)),
    color-stop(1, rgb(62,184,229))
    );
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 5px;
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px #2ab7ec, 0px 5px 0px 0px #156785, 0px 10px 5px #999;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px #2ab7ec, 0px 5px 0px 0px #156785, 0px 10px 5px #999;
    -o-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px #2ab7ec, 0px 5px 0px 0px #156785, 0px 10px 5px #999;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px #2ab7ec, 0px 5px 0px 0px #156785, 0px 10px 5px #999;
}

.a_demo_three:active {
    top:3px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(62,184,229) 0%, rgb(44,160,202) 100%);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(62,184,229) 0%, rgb(44,160,202) 100%);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(62,184,229) 0%, rgb(44,160,202) 100%);
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(62,184,229) 0%, rgb(44,160,202) 100%);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(62,184,229) 0%, rgb(44,160,202) 100%);
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(
    linear,
    left bottom,
    left top,
    color-stop(0, rgb(62,184,229)),
    color-stop(1, rgb(44,160,202))
    );
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px #2ab7ec, 0px 2px 0px 0px #156785, 0px 5px 3px #999;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px #2ab7ec, 0px 2px 0px 0px #156785, 0px 5px 3px #999;
    -o-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px #2ab7ec, 0px 2px 0px 0px #156785, 0px 5px 3px #999;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px #2ab7ec, 0px 2px 0px 0px #156785, 0px 5px 3px #999;
}

.a_demo_three::before {
    background-color:#2561b4;
    content:"1";
    width:35px;
    max-height:29px;
    height:100%;
    position:absolute;
    display:block;
    padding-top:8px;
    top:0px;
    left:-36px;
    font-size:16px;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#8fd1ea;
    text-shadow:1px 1px 0px #07526e;
    border-right:solid 1px #07526e;
    background-image: linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(10,94,125) 0%, rgb(14,139,184) 100%);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(10,94,125) 0%, rgb(14,139,184) 100%);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(10,94,125) 0%, rgb(14,139,184) 100%);
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(10,94,125) 0%, rgb(14,139,184) 100%);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(10,94,125) 0%, rgb(14,139,184) 100%);
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(
    linear,
    left bottom,
    left top,
    color-stop(0, rgb(10,94,125)),
    color-stop(1, rgb(14,139,184))
    );
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 5px;
    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px #2ab7ec, 0px 5px 0px 0px #032b3a, 0px 10px 5px #999 ;
    -moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px #2ab7ec, 0px 5px 0px 0px #032b3a, 0px 10px 5px #999 ;
    -o-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px #2ab7ec, 0px 5px 0px 0px #032b3a, 0px 10px 5px #999 ;
    box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px #2ab7ec, 0px 5px 0px 0px #032b3a, 0px 10px 5px #999 ;
}

.a_demo_three:active::before {
    top:-3px;
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px #2ab7ec, 0px 5px 0px 0px #032b3a, 1px 1px 0px 0px #044a64, 2px 2px 0px 0px #044a64, 2px 5px 0px 0px #044a64, 6px 4px 2px #0b698b, 0px 10px 5px #999 ;
    -moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px #2ab7ec, 0px 5px 0px 0px #032b3a, 1px 1px 0px 0px #044a64, 2px 2px 0px 0px #044a64, 2px 5px 0px 0px #044a64, 6px 4px 2px #0b698b, 0px 10px 5px #999 ;
    -o-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px #2ab7ec, 0px 5px 0px 0px #032b3a, 1px 1px 0px 0px #044a64, 2px 2px 0px 0px #044a64, 2px 5px 0px 0px #044a64, 6px 4px 2px #0b698b, 0px 10px 5px #999 ;
    box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px #2ab7ec, 0px 5px 0px 0px #032b3a, 1px 1px 0px 0px #044a64, 2px 2px 0px 0px #044a64, 2px 5px 0px 0px #044a64, 6px 4px 2px #0b698b, 0px 10px 5px #999 ;
}

/*
Third button
*/

.third_button::before {
    content: url('menu.png');
}
```

Script:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#trt a').click(function(e){ //where menu is the id of your menu item
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#tst').slideToggle(); // where content is the id of your content div
    });


    //ORIGINALLY THE MENU should be hidden out of the user's view.
    //ON CLICKING ON MENU the `tst` div will slide down, the menu button should be in `active` status.
    //ON CLICKING ON MENU again the `tst` div will slide up and out of view and the menu button should be in `normal` status
});
</script>
```

What I am looking to do is have the `tst` div out of view when the page loads. When the user clicks on the `a` link which is a button, the `tst` div should slide to the right and be placed on right of the link.

Starts with this:

[image]

When the user clicks on the menu the `tst` div should animate and slide to the right and should look like this:

[image]

Finally, when the user clicks on the menu link again, the `tst` div slide to the left and out of the user's view.

How do I achieve that?

Comment: glad to see a fresh, never before asked question, after a while :)

Comment: I deleted the other one as it wasn't explained correctly and opened a new question with the proper codes and documentation.

Comment: Weird it works in JSFiddle but not in my webpage :/

Comment: Are you looking for something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/borglinm/sp3ju/

Comment: @Mathias Yes exactly, but two things. The menu should be placed to the right of the button and when clicking twice the div should slide back to the left away from the user's view.

Comment: waw i think i will use this css looks nice menu :)

Comment: @echo_Me Doesn't work in IE < 10 other than that it's a great piece of code and graphic!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this fiddle. Added `float: left` to both the button and menu http://jsfiddle.net/borglinm/sp3ju/3/

JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#trt a').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log($('#tst').css("left"));
        if($('#tst').css("left") === "-350px") {
        $('#tst').animate({"left": 0});
        }
        else
        {
            $('#tst').animate({"left": -350});
        }
    });
});
```

Relevant CSS addition

```
body {
    margin: 0;
}

.a_demo_three {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at this: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/siva_hari/Fkqgv/).

Added `float:left` to both the divs.

Comment: Almost there, not it needs to slide in from the left and slide out to the left.

Comment: Also I have some other DIVS under it and would like this sliding to happen without pushing the other DIVS down...

Comment: Can you update the HTML in your question to reflect the additional divs along with any CSS? I just need to see your layout before I suggest any changes.